# Python multiprocessing Deadlock using Queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have a python program like below.

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
import time

lock = Lock()


def do_job(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done):
    while not tasks_to_accomplish.empty():
        task = tasks_to_accomplish.get()
        print(task)
        lock.acquire()
        tasks_that_are_done.put(task + ' is done by ' + current_process().name)
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(1)
    return True


def main():
    number_of_task = 10
    number_of_processes = 4
    tasks_to_accomplish = Queue()
    tasks_that_are_done = Queue()
    processes = []

    for i in range(number_of_task):
        tasks_to_accomplish.put("Task no " + str(i))

    # creating processes
    for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=do_job, args=(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()


    # completing process
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # print the output
    while not tasks_that_are_done.empty():
        print(tasks_that_are_done.get())

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sometimes program run perfectly but sometimes it gets stuck and doesn't complete. When quit manually, it produces following error.

```
$ python3 multiprocessing_example.py 
Task no 0
Task no 1
Task no 2
Task no 3
Task no 4
Task no 5
Task no 6
Task no 7
Task no 8
Task no 9
^CProcess Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing_example.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "multiprocessing_example.py", line 37, in main
    p.join()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 51, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 29, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "multiprocessing_example.py", line 9, in do_job
    task = tasks_to_accomplish.get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 94, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Can someone tell me what is the issue with the program? I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note**: `Lock` is not needed around a `Queue`.
>
> ```
>     lock.acquire()
>     tasks_that_are_done.put(task + ' is done by ' + current_process().name)
>     lock.release()
> ```
>
> [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)
>   The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics.

---

> **Question**: ... what is the issue with the program?

You are using `Queue.empty()` and `Queue.get()`, 
such leads to **Deadlock** on calling `join()` because there is no guarantee that the **`empty()`** State don't change until **`get()`**
was reaching.

> **Deadlock prone**:
>
> ```
> while not tasks_to_accomplish.empty():
>     task = tasks_to_accomplish.get()
> ```

Instead of using `empty/get`, Pair use for instance:

```
import queue
while True:
    try:
        task = tasks_to_accomplish.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        break
    else:
        # Handle task here
        ...
        tasks_to_accomplish.task_done()
```